# Java.util.Calendar.add() function in scala

Tags: scala

```
val  now = Calendar.getInstance();
val toDt= now.get(Calendar.MONTH)
val fromDt= now.add(Calendar.MONTH,-6)
```

I am trying fetch minus 6 month date value by using above code. Looks like now.add is generating Unit value

Answer (score 1):

```
val fromDt = now.clone().asInstanceOf[Calendar]
fromDt.add(Calendar.MONTH, -6) // after call `add` method, the `fromDt` internal state has changed, so you can use `fromDt` directly. like below `print`
println(fromDt.get(Calendar.MONTH))
> 7
```

You can `clone` calendar and add **Month**.

Comment: `val  now = Calendar.getInstance();
        val toDt= now.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        val tempDt = now.clone().asInstanceOf[Calendar]
        val fromDt = tempDt.add(Calendar.MONTH, -6)
        println(fromDt)`

Comment: I still see as a Unit.

Comment: Environment: Scala 2.10

Comment: after you call `add` method, the `fromDt` state has changed, so you can use the `fromDt` for your later operation.